# Want to add two value in {{}} in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a form like this

```
<form>
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
     <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Percent"  formControlName="txtTaxLinePerc"   (change)="changeTotal()">
         <span matSuffix>%</span>            
      </mat-form-field>
  </div>    
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
     <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
       <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Percent"  formControlName="txtCompoundTaxPerc" (change)="changeTotal()">
        <span matSuffix>%</span>            
      </mat-form-field>
  </div>
<form>
<span>{{get added value}}</span>
```

this is my ts code

```
 get txtTaxLinePerc()  {   
    return this.addTaxTypeForm.controls.txtTaxLinePerc
  }

  get txtCompoundTaxPerc()  { 
    return this.addTaxTypeForm.controls.txtCompoundTaxPerc
    }
```

I want to show the added value of txtTaxLinePerc and txtCompoundTaxPerc
How can I do that.

I have tried adding `{{txtTaxLinePerc.value+txtCompoundTaxPerc.value}}` but it does not add it just concatenate the values like this `20+40` it will give `2040`

Comment: Did you try this "<span> {{txtTaxLinePerc }} {{txtCompoundTaxPerc}} </span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{{txtTaxLinePerc + txtCompoundTaxPerc}}
```

**Changes to your Component file**

```
get txtTaxLinePerc()  {   
  return this.addTaxTypeForm.controls.txtTaxLinePerc.value
}

get txtCompoundTaxPerc()  { 
  return this.addTaxTypeForm.controls.txtCompoundTaxPerc.value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`<span>{{txtTaxLinePerc + txtCompoundTaxPerc}}</span>`

and also change your `.ts` file

```
get txtTaxLinePerc()  {   
  return this.addTaxTypeForm.controls.txtTaxLinePerc.value
}

get txtCompoundTaxPerc()  { 
  return this.addTaxTypeForm.controls.txtCompoundTaxPerc.value
}
```

because now you return an [`AbstractControl`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl) and you want to get the value from it

Answer (score 1):

In your component class

```
sum: any
```

And in changeTotal() method

```
 changeTotal(){
     ...
    sum = txtTaxLinePerc  +txtCompoundTaxPerc;
    ...
    }
```

And bind this sum in span

```
<span>{{sum}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `formGroup` directive to your form if you want to use ReactiveForms. Then you can take value of input by `addTaxTypeForm.get('txtTaxLinePerc').value`.

So you can edit your gettes

```
get txtTaxLinePerc()  {   
    return this.addTaxTypeForm.get('txtTaxLinePerc').value
}

get txtCompoundTaxPerc()  { 
    return this.addTaxTypeForm.get('txtCompoundTaxPerc').value
}
```

And in your html:

```
{{ txtTaxLinePerc + txtCompoundTaxPerc}}
```